# Is it possible to find times of past user sessions?

Tags: linux, users, logs, session

Using the `who` command, I can find which users are currently logged into a machine.

I would like to determine which users have logged into my machine in the past, and the length of those sessions. Is this information retained, and can I access it?

The particular machine I'm thinking of is running Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `last` command for this.  It will tell you who logged in, what port/tty, date, time and duration of the session.

Here is the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?last)

FWIW, every installation of Ubuntu I've had, had this command available.